# Transform or replace html file in Visual Studio on publish

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I have a static HTML-file in a project, which I want to transform/replace when I publish/build the solution. Is this possible without adding any server-side code to the file itself?

Let's say I have a HTML-file in the root of my application as such:

**www.example.com/serverinfo.html**

The file will have the static content:

```
SERVER1;www.example.com
```

But when i run this locally I would like it to render

```
SERVER1;www.example.local
```

The file should be accessibe without any server-side processing and cannot contain any code. I'm used to web.config transformations. Is there any possibility that this can be applied to a HTML-file as well? Or is it just applicable to web.config?

I would like to have a structure similiar to the one with web.config:

```
serverinfo.html
serverinfo.html.debug
serverinfo.html.release
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and is usually deploying to Azure. I now I can manually add a static file to the server, but I would really like to have this managed in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a simpler way, but I ended up making a build script.

```
  <Target Name="ApplySpecificProxy" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\build\proxy\serverinfo.$(Configuration).html')" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text='Copying Proxy.html' Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\build\proxy\proxy.$(Configuration).html"
          DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\serverinfo.html" ContinueOnError="false"  />
  </Target>
```